How deserialize langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage
I would like to reconstruct an object of langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage from the dict obtained from an object of type langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage.
Is there a constructor I can use?
The documentation of "langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage" seems not to include information on the construction of "langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage" objects.

This is how I am able to construct a new instance of langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage from dict.
The dictionary returned by langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage.dict() contains the data necessary to construct a new instance of langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage.
Below is an example how I am able to make use of the dict obtained from chat_h_item2 variable of type langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage and construct a new object of langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage in variable chat_h_item3.
chat_h_item2_dict: dict=chat_h_item2.dict();
chat_h_item3: langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage=langchain_core.messages.ai.AIMessage(chat_h_item2_dict["content"]);
chat_h_item3.response_metadata=chat_h_item2_dict["response_metadata"];
chat_h_item3.id=chat_h_item2_dict["id"];
chat_h_item3.example=chat_h_item2_dict["example"];
chat_h_item3.name=chat_h_item2_dict["name"];
chat_h_item3.tool_calls=chat_h_item2_dict["tool_calls"];
chat_h_item3.invalid_tool_calls=chat_h_item2_dict["invalid_tool_calls"];
chat_h_item3_dict: dict=chat_h_item3.dict();
logger_obj.info("chat_h_item2_dict is:'{0}'".format(json.dumps(chat_h_item2_dict,indent=4,sort_keys=False)));
logger_obj.info("chat_h_item3_dict is:'{0}'".format(json.dumps(chat_h_item3_dict,indent=4,sort_keys=False)));

